# SQL subtract same column values by conditional rows and insert new results on a table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this code in Snowflake to obtain the following table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE LIVE_ANALYTICS.REPORTING."GL_REPORT"
AS
SELECT
    SUM("TABLE_GL_ENTRY"."Amount" AS "AMOUNT",
    MONTH("TABLE_GL_ENTRY"."Posting Date") AS "MONTH",
    YEAR("TABLE_GL_ENTRY"."Posting Date") AS "YEAR",
    "TABLE_GL_ENTRY"."Global Dimension 1 Code" AS "ID_STORE",
    CASE
        WHEN "YEAR" = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) THEN 'AMOUNT_CURRENT_YEAR'
        ELSE 'AMOUNT_LAST_YEAR'
    END AS "METRIC"
FROM
    LIVE_ANALYTICS.NAVISION."G_L Entry" AS "TABLE_GL_ENTRY"
WHERE
    (("MONTH" = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) OR "MONTH" = MONTH(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, 1)))
    AND
    ("YEAR" = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) OR "YEAR" = YEAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12))))
    AND
    (("ID_STORE" LIKE '1')
        OR
    ("ID_STORE" LIKE '2')
        OR
    ("ID_STORE" LIKE '3'))    
GROUP BY
    MONTH",
    "YEAR",
    "ID_STORE",
;
```

[image]

From this table I need to subtract "AMOUNT" by "MONTH" and "ID_STORE" **only if "YEAR" = 2021**.

```
AMOUNT_CURRENT_YEAR - AMOUNT_LAST_YEAR
```

[image]

**Finally, I want to insert these new results into the existing table with the other existing records.**

[image]

How can I do this? Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Kind regards.

EDIT: This is the solution that i searched last days, thank you everyone!

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9909600b9ac804ba67b7086c40e0c844

```
create table last_amount as 
select sum(amount) as 'amount_last', month, year, id, metric 
from data where metric like 'last' 
group by month, year, id, metric 
order by id, month, year;

create table current_amount as 
select sum(amount) as 'amount_current', month, year, id, metric 
from data where metric like 'current' 
group by month, year, id, metric 
order by id, month, year

create table subtract as
select
c.amount_current - l.amount_last as amount, c.month, c.year, c.id
from
last_amount l
join
current_amount c
on
l.id = c.id
and
l.month = c.month;

alter table subtract add metric varchar(255) default 'subtract';

insert into data
select * from subtract;

drop table last_amount;
drop table current_amount;

select * from data order by id, month, year;
```

Comment: Snowflake is not MySQL.

Comment: can you please post the data and your current code in the text format and not pictures

Comment: Hi @trillion, edit with my code, I don't know how continue...

Comment: @MiquelMartorell check the answer below might help you

Comment: @MiquelMartorell did it work for you ?

Comment: Sorry @forpas, is an error because I had testing with another data, I will edit to 12, thank you!

Comment: Good morning @trillion, thank you for your help but I have not been able to achieve the desired results. I would like it to only calculate the difference from the current year - previous year only on rows containing records from the current year. Is this possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: @MiquelMartorell did you check this ? I am not sure what is wrong here.`` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ad1e26d11b1c835fc77e9c4578bebf5 ```

Comment: hi @trillion, i checked this: 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3021fb22ee11cb42ae82da6588c95d2d
You can see that the results are not the desired. The final table are not the same that my desired final table. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better option:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4273a6e920b54e118868ca44a5927cce

```
create table data ( amount int, month  int, year int,  id int, metric 
varchar(255) );
insert into data values (10, 8, 2020, 1, 'last');
insert into data values (20, 8, 2021, 1, 'current');
insert into data values (30, 8, 2020, 2, 'last');
insert into data values (60, 8, 2021, 3, 'current');
insert into data values (70, 9, 2020, 1, 'last');
insert into data values (0,  9, 2021, 1, 'current');
insert into data values (90, 9, 2020, 2, 'last');
insert into data values (40, 8, 2021, 2, 'current');
insert into data values (50, 8, 2020, 3, 'last');
insert into data values (0,  9, 2021, 2, 'current');
insert into data values (110, 9, 2020, 3, 'last');
insert into data values (0,  9, 2021, 3, 'current');
select * from data order by id, month, year

select * from data
union all
select
c.amount - l.amount as amount, c.month, c.year, c.id, 'subtract' as metric
from
(select * from data where year = 2021) c
left join
(select * from data where year = 2020) l
on
l.id = c.id
and
l.month = c.month
order by id, month, year, metric;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation and `insert`:

```
insert into LIVE_ANALYTICS.NAVISION."G_L Entry" (amount, month, year, id_store, metric)
    select sum(case when metric = 'AMOUNT_CURRENT_YEAR' then amount
                    when metric = 'AMOUNT_LAST_YEAR' then - amount
               end),   
           month, year, id_store, 'SUBTRACT_LAST_YEAR'
    from LIVE_ANALYTICS.NAVISION."G_L Entry" gl
    where year = 2021
    group by month, year, id_store;
```

Comment: Hi @gordon-linoff, your insert and conditional aggregation insert a new row by every table's row existing. I only  want to subtract "AMOUNT" by "MONTH" and "ID_STORE" if "YEAR" = 2021 and the operation must be "AMOUNT_CURRENT_YEAR (2021) - AMOUNT_LAST_YEAR (2020)". Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MiquelMartorell . . . Just have a `where` clause for that (which I added to the query).

Comment: Hi @gordon-linoff, it insert correctly, but the record inserted is the amount of 2021, not the subtract, any suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here this might help you, this code might not contain all the values but it will give you an idea of the logic.

Use the link for an example:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ad1e26d11b1c835fc77e9c4578bebf5

- FIRST  : Select all data
- Second : Introduce the `lead ()` function to move the latest row 1 backwards
- Third : Subtract based on your logic
- Fourth : Joining both original and new results using `UNION`

```
with all_data as (

select * from data

),

last_year_current_year as (

select 

*,
lead(amount) over(partition by id, month, year) as one_less

from all_data

)
,

subtraction as  (

select 

*,

one_less - amount as new_amount

from last_year_current_year



),

combining_data as (

select new_amount, month, year, id from subtraction

union

select amount, month, year, id from subtraction

)

select * from combining_data
```

Answer (score 0):

-- this is in SQL Server but I hope the logic will be the same in MySql as well
create table #temp1
(
Amount money,
MonthNum int,
YearNum int,
ID_Store int,
Metric varchar(100)
);

insert into #temp1 values(10,8,2020,1,'AMOUNT LAST YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(20,8,2021,1,'AMOUNT CURRENT YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(30,8,2020,2,'AMOUNT LAST YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(40,8,2021,2,'AMOUNT CURRENT YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(50,8,2020,3,'AMOUNT LAST YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(60,8,2021,3,'AMOUNT CURRENT YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(70,9,2020,1,'AMOUNT__YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(0,9,2021,1,'AMOUNT CURRENT YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(90,9,2020,2,'AMOUNT__YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(0,9,2021,2,'AMOUNT CURRENT YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(110,9,2020,3,'AMOUNT__YEAR')
insert into #temp1 values(0,9,2021,3,'AMOUNT CURRENT YEAR')

-- start the actual code starts from here
Select
(t1.Amount-t3.Amount) as Amount
,t1.MonthNum
,t1.YearNum
,t1.ID_Store
,'Modified Metric' as Metric
into #temp2
from #temp1 t1
join (Select t2.Amount,t2.MonthNum,t2.ID_Store from #temp1 t2 where t2.YearNum=2020) t3 ON t1.MonthNum=t3.MonthNum and t1.ID_Store=t3.ID_Store
where t1.YearNum=2021

insert into #temp1
select * from #temp2

-- End the actual code starts from here

Select * from #temp1;

drop table #temp1;
drop table #temp2;

Comment: Hi @sandeep, i have an error in your code: Undeclared variable: temp2, can you check this? 

Thank you in advance.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32405cec94d91e15a8a9c5adbca855c0

Answer (score 0):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9909600b9ac804ba67b7086c40e0c844

```
create table data ( amount int, month  int, year int,  id int, metric varchar(255) );


insert into data values (10, 8, 2020, 1, 'last');
insert into data values (20, 8, 2021, 1, 'current');
insert into data values (30, 8, 2020, 2, 'last');
insert into data values (60, 8, 2021, 3, 'current');
insert into data values (70, 9, 2020, 1, 'last');
insert into data values (0,  9, 2021, 1, 'current');
insert into data values (90, 9, 2020, 2, 'last');
insert into data values (40, 8, 2021, 2, 'current');
insert into data values (50, 8, 2020, 3, 'last');
insert into data values (0,  9, 2021, 2, 'current');
insert into data values (110, 9, 2020, 3, 'last');
insert into data values (0,  9, 2021, 3, 'current');

select * from data order by id, month, year

create table last_amount as 
select sum(amount) as 'amount_last', month, year, id, metric 
from data where metric like 'last' 
group by month, year, id, metric 
order by id, month, year;

create table current_amount as 
select sum(amount) as 'amount_current', month, year, id, metric 
from data where metric like 'current' 
group by month, year, id, metric 
order by id, month, year

create table subtract as
select
c.amount_current - l.amount_last as amount, c.month, c.year, c.id
from
last_amount l
join
current_amount c
on
l.id = c.id
and
l.month = c.month;

alter table subtract add metric varchar(255) default 'subtract';

insert into data
select * from subtract;

drop table last_amount;
drop table current_amount;

select * from data order by id, month, year;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a50ae3dce1eda02250d79fbb6f95ca7

```
create table data ( amount int, month  int, year int,  id int, metric varchar(255) );


insert into data values (10, 8, 2020, 1, 'last');
insert into data values (20, 8, 2021, 1, 'current');
insert into data values (30, 8, 2020, 2, 'last');
insert into data values (60, 8, 2021, 3, 'current');
insert into data values (70, 9, 2020, 1, 'last');
insert into data values (0,  9, 2021, 1, 'current');
insert into data values (90, 9, 2020, 2, 'last');
insert into data values (40, 8, 2021, 2, 'current');
insert into data values (50, 8, 2020, 3, 'last');
insert into data values (0,  9, 2021, 2, 'current');
insert into data values (110, 9, 2020, 3, 'last');
insert into data values (0,  9, 2021, 3, 'current');
select * from data order by id, month, year


select * from data
union all
select
c.amount - l.amount as amount, c.month, c.year, c.id, 'subtract' as metric
from
data c
right join
data l
on
l.id = c.id
and
l.month = c.month
where c.year = 2021
and c.amount - l.amount != 0
order by id, month, year;
```